# Selected combobox item in textbox, picturebox XML (XDocument)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I display all the values of the item selected in the combobox into the textbox, picturebox ... My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Animals>
  <Anim id="26">
    <Name>Master Yi</Name>
    <Image>D:\Hobbies\images\MasterYi.png</Image>
    <Description>Description Here</Description>
    <item1>ImageLocation</item1>
  </Anim>
</Animals>
```

I have these code which fill my combobox

```
void FillComboBox()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        var doc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "animals.xml"));
        comboBox1.DataSource = doc.Root.Elements()
.Select(e => new { Id = e.Attribute("id").Value, Name = e.Element("Name").Value })
.ToList();
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
}
```

I can not associate the output code with the selected item. I know that I need to put id in the Parse command. But how exactly this is realized, I do not understand.I need it on my main form (only view) and on Edit form (for editing selected element and save)
xmlDocument same code which I want in XDocument

```
labelName.Text = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                pictureBoxImg.ImageLocation = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
                textBoxDescription.Text = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
                pictureBoxItem1.ImageLocation = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ChildNodes[3].InnerText;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain more about the behavior you wanted to accomplish?

Comment: Okay.I'll try as simple as possible. I fill the combobox with the ID attribute and output the NAME of each element in the XML file (There are several of them). If I select one of the elements in the combobox, the inherent fields (name, image, description) are displayed in the corresponding text fields. You can say this as an online store. On the form there are the same fields, which are filled in accordance with XML file. Code fill combobox is up here. I can show my resolve by xmlDocument if you want it as example

Comment: I add same code in xmlDocument what I want in XDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

You need to add the using System.Xml.Linq; namespace

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private XDocument _xmlDoc;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "animals.xml"));
        FillComboBox();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox1OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void ComboBox1OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        var selectedIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;
        var selectedValue = cmb.SelectedValue;

        if (_xmlDoc.Root == null) return;
        var animal = (from el in _xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Anim")
                      where (string)el.Attribute("id") == selectedValue.ToString()
                      select el);

        var imagePath = animal.Select(x => x.Element("Image").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @imagePath;
        txtName.Text = cmb.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        var description = animal.Select(x => x.Element("Description").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        txtDescription.Text = description;
        var itemOne = animal.Select(x => x.Element("item1").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        txtItem.Text = itemOne;
    }

    void FillComboBox()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

        comboBox1.DataSource = _xmlDoc.Root.Elements()
            .Select(e => new { Id = e.Attribute("id").Value, Name = e.Element("Name").Value })
            .ToList();
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Saga Yes, great! Just I can`t something understand... This still not work until I add "Load" into FillComboBox.It`s normaly work for you or my mistake somewhere?

Comment: XDocument of the loaded XML should be accessible for further processing/ filtering.  The variable var doc you used is only local to the method FillComboBox and can't be used outside that method. Declare and load outside like I did.

Comment: If you see I did not Load the XML in FillComboBox method. I just accessed it as I already loaded the xml in Form load.

Comment: oh sorry.It was my bad, I just not delete FillComboBox method from InitializeComponent section

Comment: I have one more question.How can I refresh items list after add? I have Add form and this add new item in XML.How I can refresh XML in main form after closing Add?

Comment: One way I can think of is you can Hide the Main Form when you open the Add Form. Once you Close the Add Form you can instantiate the Main form and show the same. There Could be lot of better ways to achieve this, you need to do some research. Happy Coding.